# titlesec: different formats for numbered and unnumbered sections/chapters

Tags: titlesec

I'm not sure if this is too minimal. (In the real document the problem appears at the bibliography, table of contents and `\chapter*`)

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=3cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\normalfont\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\LARGE\thechapter\quad}

\begin{document}
\chapter*{Not numbered}
\chapter{Numbered}
\end{document}
```

How do I get the `\thechapter\quad` to not apply for unnumbered chapters?

Comment: For numbered chapters, do you want  the chapter number and chapter title on the same line or on different lines.? This is not clear from your code.

Comment: @Bernard Same line

Comment: So my proposition was correct. Chapter title is left-aligned. Also, do you want unnumbered chapters to appear in the table of contents?

Comment: @Bernard Yes. I currently use \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Preface} locally, but is it possible automate that operation?

Comment: Yes. See my updated answer. You have to load  `titlesec` with the `explicit` option. And hypothetically use `titletoc` to define a correct formatting of unnumbered chapters in the table of contents.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I understand what you want to do, you should use the `block`style. Add something like this to your preamble:

```
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}[block]{\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}#1}
```

Also, replace your present code for numbered chapters with

```
\titleformat{\chapter}[block]{\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries}{\thechapter}{1em}{#1}
```