# Changing the TOC in the document class book so that it's not a chapter

Tags: table-of-contents, titlesec

I want to use the titlesec package to format the chapter titles but apparently the TOC is then also formated this way. How do I make it so the TOC does not get affected?

[image]

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titlesec,calc,xcolor}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\fontsize{18}{16}\usefont{OT1}{phv}{m}{n}\bfseries}{}{0pt}{
    \raisebox{-5mm}[0pt][0pt]{%<<
        \begin{minipage}{20mm}
            \centering{\mdseries\footnotesize\normalsize\textsc{chapter}}\\[5pt]%
            \rule{10mm}{30mm}\hspace{-10mm}%
            \raisebox{23mm}{\parbox{10mm}{\centering\LARGE\textcolor{white}{\thechapter}}}%
        \end{minipage}
    }%
    \rule{\textwidth-22mm}{.4pt}\\%
    \hspace*{22mm}\begin{minipage}{\textwidth-22mm}
    }[\end{minipage}\vspace*{10mm}]



\begin{document}
    
    \tableofcontents
    \chapter{chapter 1}
    \chapter{chapter 2}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: You need to also provide a design for un-numbered chapters (removing the work "chapter" and the number from the current design would look nice). Though I don't know the `titlesec` interface to do that.

Comment: This answer seems to be the proper approach: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/245301/3929

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `\titleformat` after `\tableofcontents`

[image: a]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{calc,xcolor}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\begin{document}

    \tableofcontents
    
    \titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\fontsize{18}{16}\usefont{OT1}{phv}{m}{n}\bfseries}{}{0pt}{
        \raisebox{-5mm}[0pt][0pt]{%<<
            \begin{minipage}{20mm}
                \centering{\mdseries\footnotesize\normalsize\textsc{chapter}}\\[5pt]%
                \rule{10mm}{30mm}\hspace{-10mm}%
                \raisebox{23mm}{\parbox{10mm}{\centering\LARGE\textcolor{white}{\thechapter}}}%
            \end{minipage}
        }%
        \rule{\textwidth-22mm}{.4pt}\\%
        \hspace*{22mm}\begin{minipage}{\textwidth-22mm}
        }[\end{minipage}\vspace*{10mm}] 
    

    \chapter{chapter 1}
    \chapter{chapter 2}

    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Well, that does the trick! Thank you for pointing out that completely obvious but elegant fix. However, I'm still wondering as to why this is necessary in the first place. Do you happen to know the reason behind the TOC being automatically set to be chapter 0? It does not make much sense to me.

Comment: @YellowCake The ToC is typeset with a style of a non numbered chapter and therefore does not increase the chapter counter. The current chapter number is still zero. If you put `\tableofcontents` at the end it will have the number 2 attached.

Comment: I'm afraid that still does not really clarify it for me. Is there a plausible reason behind this typeset?

Comment: @YellowCake Have you ever seen a published document with a heading like "Chapter 1 Table of Contents"?.

Comment: @PeterWilson My problem is not that the chapter number does not increase. My problem is why it is a chapter in the first place.

Comment: @YellowCake Generally speaking, the ToC is just a list to introduce the reader to the relevant content of the document and provide a quick way to access  it by providing its page number.

The designers of the main LaTex classes chose to compose the ToC header as an unnumbered chapter,  so it is not included in the ToC, and named Content as default. You can choose a completely different name and style, include it in the ToC, etc.. There are many packages to help you do it effortlessly.

Comment: @YellowCake LaTeX has two representations of a typeset "chapter". `\chapter` for numbered chapters including "Chapter" and the title. `\chapter*` for just the title with no "Chapter" or number. I think that you need to differentiate between the general meaning of "chapter" and the specific LaTeX forms of `\chapter `.

Answer (score 1):

One can use the answer from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/245301/3929 to be able to have one design for numbered items and another for un-numbered.

Here I adjusted the current numbered design for the un-numbered by removing `\thechapter` and by wrapping the word `Chapter` by `\phantom` such that they are placed the same vertically.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titlesec,calc,xcolor}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}[display]{\fontsize{18}{16}\usefont{OT1}{phv}{m}{n}\bfseries}{}{0pt}{
    \raisebox{-5mm}[0pt][0pt]{%<<
        \begin{minipage}{20mm}
            \centering{\mdseries\footnotesize\normalsize\phantom{\textsc{chapter}}}\\[5pt]%
            \rule{10mm}{30mm}\hspace{-10mm}%
            \raisebox{23mm}{\parbox{10mm}{\centering\LARGE\textcolor{white}{}}}%
        \end{minipage}
    }%
    \rule{\textwidth-22mm}{.4pt}\\%
    \hspace*{22mm}\begin{minipage}{\textwidth-22mm}
    }[\end{minipage}\vspace*{10mm}]



\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\fontsize{18}{16}\usefont{OT1}{phv}{m}{n}\bfseries}{}{0pt}{
    \raisebox{-5mm}[0pt][0pt]{%<<
        \begin{minipage}{20mm}
            \centering{\mdseries\footnotesize\normalsize\textsc{chapter}}\\[5pt]%
            \rule{10mm}{30mm}\hspace{-10mm}%
            \raisebox{23mm}{\parbox{10mm}{\centering\LARGE\textcolor{white}{\thechapter}}}%
        \end{minipage}
    }%
    \rule{\textwidth-22mm}{.4pt}\\%
    \hspace*{22mm}\begin{minipage}{\textwidth-22mm}
    }[\end{minipage}\vspace*{10mm}]



\begin{document}
    
    \tableofcontents
    \chapter{chapter 1}
    \chapter{chapter 2}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I like your answer as it applies to anything that uses `\chapter*` (an unnumbered chapter) wherever it might occur in the document.